# How to save value from drop down which is populated from database?

Tags: mysql, jsp, drop-down-menu

I have populated the dropdown in JSP from a MySQL database and I need to save it according to the value which user selects.  How do I achieve this? The code is as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr><td>Select Salesperson:</td><td>
       <select name="sale">
         <option  selected="Please Select">---Please select---</option>
         <%  while(resultset.next()){  %>
           <option><%= resultset.getString(1)%></option>
          <% } %>
       </select>
   <tr><td>Select Outlet:</td><td>
       <select>
          <option  selected="Please Select">---Please select---</option>
          <%  while(rs2.next()){ %>
            <option><%= rs2.getString(1)%></option>
          <%  } %>
      </select>
</table>
```

Comment: Wait what do you actually want to do..? Do you want us to write the code for inserting data into your db? look into ajax...

Comment: I dont want to write into the DB is just want to populate another drop down by this value, how to acheive it.?

Comment: You want to access it using javascript..?

Comment: yep, how could i do it?

Comment: You would use ajax requests to mini pages (or servlets rather) that only display one dropdown per page but take in parameters of the previous dropdowns. And to make things simple you would use jquery for the Ajax calls.